# Script to apply formulas to cell drop-down

Tags: google-apps-script

I am making a status tracker sheet that has a column for the status of each task. Right now, Column D is has the status for each task and is set up with a drop down menu:

- No action needed
- Needs attention
- In progress
- Complete

Column E has the due date for each task.

Is there a way to write a script for the drop down menu that will change the status of cells that say "No Action Needed" to "Needs attention" once the **due date** is within a week of the **current date**?

Also, what's the best way to incorporate **email notifications** into the script so that any time a status changes to "Needs attention", an email is sent to the owner in Column F?

Answer (score 0):

This would definitely be possible through the built-in script editor.

Overall you would want to be able to interact with the sheet that this is data is stored in. The easiest way to do this is through the [SpreadsheetApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app) class and methods.

For the first step, you would want to set up a script that checks whether the due date is within a week of the current date. This can be done using the [Javascript Date Methods](https://www.w3schools.com/jS/js_date_methods.asp) which can easily be compared using regular number operations such as subtraction and addition.

The second part of the script would be possible using the built-in apps script functions of [MailApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/mail/mail-app#sendEmail(Object)).

When you have both of these parts of the scripts down, you should tie it to a [trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/) to ensure that the script will trigger at either given times (time-driven triggers) or at given events (event-triggers).